# Spring - How to test Controller with ApplicationEventPublisher dependency?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, event-handling

I have a Controller which is publishing an event

```
@RestController
public class Controller
{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @GetMapping("/event")
    public void get()
    {
        publisher.publishEvent(new Event());
    }
}
```

Now I want to test that the event is published. First I tried to @MockBean the ApplicationEventPublisher and verify the method call. But this does not work according to https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14335

So I am doing it like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest
{
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void getTest() throws Exception
    {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
        assertNotNull(Listener.event);
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Listener
    {
        public static Event event;

        @EventListener
        void listen ( Event incoming )
        {
            event = incoming;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way for this common use case?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Controller someController= new Controller(publisher);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(someController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getTest() throws Exception
    {
        ArgumentCaptor<Event> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Event.class);
        doAnswer(invocation -> {
            Event value = argumentCaptor.getValue();
             //assert if event is correct
            return null;
        }).when(publisher).publishEvent(argumentCaptor.capture());  

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        verify(publisher, times(1)).publishEvent(any(Event.class));
    }

}
```

And also change Field Injection to Constructor Injection in your controller class(It is a good practice).

```
@RestController
public class Controller
{

  private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

  @Autowired
  public Controller(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
      this.publisher = publisher;
  }
 ....
}
```

Comment: It is a very fine approach. I didn't know  :  `mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(someController).build();` Just this part is a little annoying :  `classes = MockServletContext.class` in the `@SpringBootTest`.   Is there not a built-in annotation to enable this behavior ?

Comment: @davidxxx actually that is not needed at all. It works even without that. edited my answer

Comment: It is still better so.

Comment: Ok, so the trick is to inject the Mocked publisher into the controller by hand. So you don't need MockBean but just Mock annotation.

Comment: ya, `@Mock` is enough. We have to do this way because of the bug u already mentioned

Answer (score 3):

Another possiblity would be that you replace the ApplicationEventPublisher instance on your controller with the mock instance using reflection in your test:

```
public class ControllerTest {
...
    // Collect your controller
    @Autowired
    private Controller controller;

    // Use the mock publisher
    @MockBean
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisherMock;

    // E.g. in setup set the mock publisher on your controller
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(controller, "publisher", publisherMock);
    }
...
```

Comment: For me this doesn't work because `ApplicationEventPublisher` is a whole Spring `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 3):

im facing the same problem, and for now i solve the problem using TestConfiguration:

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyUseCaseIT {

  @Autowired private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;
  @Autowired private MyService service;

@Test
  void callUseCase() {
var event = mock(MyEvent.class);
    doNothing().when(publisher).publishEvent(event);

service.useCase();

    verify(publisher).publishEvent(event);
}


@TestConfiguration
  static class MockitoPublisherConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    ApplicationEventPublisher publisher() {
      return mock(ApplicationEventPublisher.class);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Adding documentation about annotation that could make the trick https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/testing/testcontext-framework/application-events.html

Answer (score 0):

None of methods with `@MockBean private ApplicationEventPublisher publisherMock` work because `ApplicationEventPublisher` is the whole Spring `ApplicationContext`. There's a discussion [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18907) where they recommend to use `@RecordApplicationEvents` instead, but this is kind of unhandy because you have manually search through streams and all non-`ApplicationEvent`-s events are tracked as `PayloadApplicationEvent` ...

But there's a mockable workaround for that of course:

```java
@Component class EventPublisher {

  @Autowired ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

  public void publishEvent(Object event) {
    publisher.publishEvent(event);
  }

}
```